# Upgrade Windows XP Professional (32-bit) to Windows 7 Professional (32-bit): Do I have to re-install all my applications?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, installation, upgrade, windows-installation

If I'm upgrading, do I have to re-install all of my applications?  I hope not.  I don't see how re-installing the apps would help (except if the OS upgrade wipes/resets the registry)--the app files on disk would all be the same after as before.

I assume the Windows 7 upgrade just updates the WINDOWS directory?

Googling didn't answer this for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrading from WinXP to Win7 is [not supported](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: However, XP to Vista, then Vista to 7 is supported, but pricey and probably very glitchy.  Your best bet is to backup your hard disk(s), do a clean install of Windows 7 (you will need a full version, not the upgrade version), then reinstall you programs and restore your backed up files.

Comment: Actually, if moving from XP to 7, you can use the upgrade *version*, you don't require the full version. You just can't do an in-place upgrade with it, still have to do a clean install.

Answer (score 2):

Going from XP to 7 requires a full install, officially an in-place upgrade is not supported. You will need to back up your files and settings, and ensure you have the installation files and media.